# Remap or disable center-area of the clickpad/trackpad

Tags: mouse, 22.04, touchpad, trackpoint

### Situation:

The touchpad/trackpad from Lenovo Thinkpad laptops has a the lower area clickable and is split in 3 parts:
LEFT-area for main click, RIGHT-area for context click, and CENTER-area for middle/3rd-button click.

### Problem:

The middle-click is super annoying, because it always click when the main click was intended instead.

And it does several silly things:

- it pastes clipboard content in text-areas;
- it activates scrolling (and slightly moving the pointer provokes exaggerated scrolls up or down)
- it closes tabs when hover them
- it opens new tabs when hovering a link

... 95% of the times what I meant was to simply click the left-button.
It's making the whole UX frustrating.

---

---

### Question is:

*how to make the center-area of the trackpad/clickpad behave like if I clicked the left-area/left-button?*

This, without affecting:

- the 3 phisical buttons above the pad (that I still use, including the middle-button, when using the Trackpoint nipple)
- the buttons of an external mouse